# Replace string which have '[]' in shell

Tags: shell

I have tried to use replace method, like:

```bash
line='`[s]`'

inline_code=$(echo "$line" | awk -v RS='`' 'NR%2==0')

pattern='`([^`]+)`'
while [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]; do
    inline_codes+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
    line=${line/${BASH_REMATCH[0]}/%_inlinecode_%}
done
```

I expected `line` can be `%_inlinecode_%`, however the while loop will not stop.

I tried to find the problem, and I found `line` will still be `[s]`

If the string have special chars, ex: `[]`, the shell cannot replace successfully.